# Is it my css that's broken or jquery's append method?

Tags: jquery, css, append, behavior

Generating outside container (code unchanged, chrome dev tools):
[image]

Generating inside container (code unchanged, chrome dev tools):
[image]

I am using append in javascript to generate a playlist of music automatically. Before I was producing the html code through PHP and the css worked fine but now when I use append, about 50% of the time it will put itself outside of the  (see image 1 and 2 for comparison).

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
                var str;
                for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++){
                    if(data.songurl[i] != 'undefined'){
                        str = str + "<div id='playlistSubContainer' class=''><div id='playthumbContainer'><a class='playlist' href =''><img width='70' height='55' src=''/></a></div><div id='playlistUrl'><a class='playlist' href ='http://localhost:8080/lttfeed/?a='></a> - <a class='playlist' href='http://localhost:8080/lttfeed/?n='></a></div><br><div id='playlistInfo'>Location: <a class='playlist' href ='http://localhost:8080/lttfeed/?l='></a> |    Genre: | Year: <a class='playlist' href='http://localhost:8080/lttfeed/?y='></a><br>Views: <a class='playlist' href ='#'></a> | Likes: <a class='playlist' href ='#'></a> | Comments: <a class='playlist' href=''></a> | <a class='playlist' href='redditUrl'><img style='margin-bottom:-3px;'width='16' height='16' src='images/redditicon.png' /></a></div></div><div class='musicInfo' id=''></div>";
                    }
                }
                $("#playlistContainer").append(str);
});
```

It's quite a large string of HTML though it was directly converted from my working PHP html code.

Related CSS:

```
#playlistContainer {
    position:absolute;
    width:500px;
    height:75%;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color:171717;
    background-color:e0d1d1;
    margin-left:-10px;
    margin-top:10px;
}
#playlistInfo{
    font-size:12px;
    margin-top:-25px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

#playlistSubContainer{
    color:c7e9ee;
    position:relative;
    overflow: auto;
    width:504px;
    border-top: 1px solid;
    border-color:black;
    padding-top:10px;
    background-color:333333;
    display:inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0px 0 20px  #484848;
    border-left: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
    padding-right:100%;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition:.5s;
}
```

I'm really stumped by this problem. I know my css isn't that crash hot, but it works fine when I generate it using PHP and this issue only occurs when I generate it and attach it to the container using append. It is seemingly random, sometimes I can refresh the page 5 times and it will be out of the container each time, other times it will stay inside the container. Cheers for any assistance

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xcphve5L/)

Comment: you use another plugins for player ? and in that player you want to  add playlist ?

Comment: Ok here it is in JSfiddle. It works perfectly there though and not on my webpage so I guess the issue may run deeper, doesnt make sense that it works sometimes and sometimes not though :\

http://jsfiddle.net/xcphve5L/

Comment: __IDs in HTML must be unique__ As I see `id='playlistSubContainer' ` in a loop

Comment: Turned out to be a custom scroll bar library I was using. Never used JSfiddle before, incredibly useful debugging tool thanks for the recommendation.

The perils of taking shortcuts, they bite you in the ass later